# xsd: child element is missing that should be optional

Tags: xml, xsd

My xsd looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="modal">

        <xs:complexType>

            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="inputs" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element ref="string-option"></xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>

        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="string-option">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="option" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
                <xs:group ref="base-option-group"></xs:group>
                <xs:element ref="option" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="option" type="base-option-type"></xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="base-option-type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[^,]+"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:group name="base-option-group">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="option"></xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="option-selected"></xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="option-selected" type="base-option-type"></xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

What I would expect is, that `<string-option>` must at least contain one element `<option>` or `<option-selected>` (*any order*) and cannot contain more than one `<option-selected>`.

Strangely, the following xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../src/customElements/modal.xsd">
    <inputs>
        <string-option>
            <option>Option A</option>
            <option>Option B</option>
        </string-option>
    </inputs>
</modal>
```

yields the error `Child elements are missing from element 'string-option'`.

x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx   Added full xml/xsd
xxxx
xxx
xx
x

Full Error message in VS Code is

```
Child elements are missing from element 'string-option'.

The following elements are expected:
 - option
 - option
 - option-selected

Error indicated by:
 {the schema}
with code:xml(cvc-complex-type.2.4.b)
```

Comment: Which parser did you use? Doesn't it indicate what is missing?

Comment: Also is that XSD 1.0 or 1.1? For 1.0 I see an error with the schema and Xerces saying 'option and option (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles' about the complex type in `string-option`.

Comment: Saxon EE also tells me "Ambiguous content model: element particle `<option>` appears in more than one place in the content model"

Comment: I added some more information...

Comment: That is odd, in my understanding and with two processors (Xerces and Saxon) checked, your schema is not valid, so I am not sure why VS code tries to give a validation message about any XML instance document, it should say the schema is not valid. But I don't know which processor VS code uses, let's wait what others with more insight have to say.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184849/ambiguous-content-model-allowing-individual-elements-or-specific-combinations

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Well not really...

Comment: Very similar though.  I don't think you can achieve it in XSD 1.0.  Possibly only with XSD 1.1.     Your schema does come up with an errors as being Ambiguous in Visual Studio as well.